# React query - how to subscribe to a mutation state change

Tags: react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using [react query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/) in my project. I would like to know if there is a way of subscribing to mutation state from a different component. So, for example, I have some custom hooks for react query hook:

```
export const useUpdateResidence = (caseId: number) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);

    const mutation = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async (payload: UpdateResidenceRequest): Promise<CaseResponse> => {
            const { data } = await CASE_API.api.updateCase(caseId, payload);
            return data;
        },
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(["case", caseId], data);
            setError(undefined);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log("onError", error);
            setError(error);
        },
    });

    return { mutation, error };
};
```

I use this hook in another custom hook:

```
export const useOnSaveCase = () => {
    const { caseId } = useCase();
    const updateCase = useUpdateCase(caseId);
    const { reset } = useFormContext<CaseFormValues>();
    return (values: CaseFormValues) => {
        updateCase.mutation.mutate(createPayload(values), {
            onSuccess: () =>
                reset(values, {
                    keepErrors: true,
                    keepValues: true,
                    keepDefaultValues: true,
                    keepDirtyValues: true,
                }),
        });
    };
};
```

I am calling this hook `useOnSaveCase` from my component where I have the form:

```
const { getValues, watch } = useFormContext<CaseFormValues>();
const saveCase = useOnSaveCase();
const onSave = () => saveCase(getValues());
```

Now, I would like to subscribe to mutation state in a component outside of this form, so that I could listen to state changes there, for example, something like this:

```
const { caseId } = useCase();
const caseMutation = useUpdateCase(caseId);
console.log("is pending", caseMutation.mutation.isPending);
console.log("is success", caseMutation.mutation.isSuccess);
```

When I do it like this, only false is logged even when I call mutation from another component. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: mutation state is not shared between different mutation hooks, you need to use query if you need shared state. or you could do something with MutationCache, but I'm not sure if it's meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 2):

In version 5, the `useMutationState` hook was added that can access mutation data from any component, even if the mutation wasn't triggered from it:

https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/reference/useMutationState

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be for you to maintain a value in a global state (maybe redux or context store and modify that state variable within the onSucess, onError, or unsettle method).

```
const onSubmitform = () => {
    dispatch(triggerRespectiveStateUpdateFunction({isPending: true}));
    onSaveCase() // mutation function;
}

const {mutate} = useMutation(mutateFn, {onSettle: () => {             
              dispatch(triggerRespectiveStateUpdateFunction({isPending: false}));
   }
```

I hope you get the idea. you don't need to keep that state in the global store. instead you can maintain local state if both component share same parent